# Suppress header in crystal reports sub report

Tags: crystal-reports, subreport

I have a report that should have the following structure:

```
Group A.1
  Header 1
    Record Q.1
    Record Q.2
  Header 2
    Record P.1
Group A.2
  Header 1
    Record Q.3
  Header 2
    Record P.2
    Record P.3
....
```

However, wat I consistently get is this:

```
Group A.1
  Header 1
    Record Q.1
  Header 1
    Record Q.2
  Header 2
    Record P.1
Group A.2
  Header 1
    Record Q.3
  Header 2
    Record P.2
  Header 2
    Record P.3
....
```

My data is coming from two datasets that are linked together on the group key (`A`). I tried with two sub reports in the details section of the group. The sub report is rendered for each record (`Q.1` and `Q.2`), which makes sense. However, I'd like to suppress the header for each record except the first. I can't seem to figure out how to accomplish this.

I tried without sub reports but I don't know how to determine inside the details section whether I'm at the first record (`Q.1`) or the second (`Q.2`).

I also tried creating two additional adjacent sub groups instead of nested groups but that does not seem to be possible at all. I can only keep nesting sub groups, not placing subgroups next to eachother.

My data is structured as follows (from an Oracle database):

```
Dataset 1                        Dataset 2
Group A.1 | Record Q.1           Group A.1 | Record P.1
Group A.1 | Record Q.2           Group A.2 | Record P.2
Group A.2 | Record Q.3           Group A.2 | Record P.3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a parameter to the subreport called something like `suppresshead`, you can then link this to a running total field incrementing for each record resetting on change of the group field.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will work or not due to the evaluation time of subreports, but you can give it a whirl: Try using a shared variable as a switch to determine whether you should be suppressing the subreport header or not.

For example, in the header of your subreports you could have a formula that checks to see if the last subreport group value is the same as the current one; if it is, then suppress the header.

```
//initialize the shared variable in header of main report
whileprintingrecords;
shared stringvar lastSubVal := "";

//in the suppression formula for the subreport header, check the variable
//  to see if the last subreport header is the same as the current one (and suppress if true)
whileprintingrecords;
shared stringvar lastSubVal;

{table.currentGroupValue} = lastSubVal

//finally, in the subreport footer, just update lastSubVal
whileprintingrecords;
shared stringvar lastSubVal := {table.currentGroupValue}
```

Comment: You have to group in the sub report also. And Set the group 1 in the header of the sub report.Thus your problem is defenetly solved